# pyvmomi: How to get the sms.StorageManager instance?

Tags: pyvmomi

I try to get the sms.StorageManager instance in pyvmomi, and register storage provider later.
But I cannot find the way to get sms.StorageManager.
The objects I get from RetrieveContent() method is all like "sessionManager", "scheduledTaskManager", no sms.StorageManager.
Is there any way to get sms.StorageManager?

Answer (score 0):

Right now the SMS API isnt supported by pyVmomi, but there is a wrapper created by a 3rd party that supports it. Here is a link to the [pyVmomi wrapper](https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.pyvmomi_wrapper/) that supports it. This is an example they provide using their wrapper:

```
from infi.pyvmomi_wrapper import Client
from infi.pyvmomi_wrapper.sms import SmsClient
# first open a "regular" client
client = Client("vcenter-server", username="myuser", password="pass")

sms_client = SmsClient(client)
storage_manager = sms_client.service_instance.QueryStorageManager()
storage_providers = storage_manager.QueryProvider()
```